# Deployment is getting stuck in Raffle contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs

I am not able to deploy Raffle contract as it is getting stuck.
Here is image of the error.

[image: Deployment is stuck for many minutes]

It is not completing only.

Here is my Raffle contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

error Raffle_NotEnoughToEnterRaffle();
error Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
error Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    enum RaffleState {
        Open,
        Calculating
    }

    RaffleState public s_raffleState;
    address payable[] public s_players;
    uint256 public s_lastTimeStamp;
    address public s_recentWinner;
    uint256 public immutable i_entranceFee;
    uint256 public immutable i_interval;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface public immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 public immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 public immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 public immutable i_callbackGasLimit;

    uint16 public constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 public constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        uint256 entranceFee,
        uint256 interval,
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        bytes32 gasLane, // keyhash
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_interval = interval;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
    }

    function enterRaffle() external payable {
        // require(msg.value >= i_entranceFee,"Not enough money sent");

        if (msg.value >= i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle_NotEnoughToEnterRaffle();
        }
        // Checking Raffle State whether it is Open or in Calculating State
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.Open) {
            revert Raffle__RaffleNotOpen();
        }
        // You can enter!!
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    // Be true after some time interval
    // The lottery should be Open
    // The contract has ETH
    // Keepers has LINK
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public view returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory) {
        bool isOpen = RaffleState.Open == s_raffleState;
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        bool hasPlayers = s_players.length > 0;

        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) revert Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded();

        s_raffleState = RaffleState.Calculating;

        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );

        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /* requestId */,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.Open;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }
}
```

Here is my deploy code.

```js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const ENTRANCE_FEE = ethers.parseEther("0.01");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

  const args = [
    ENTRANCE_FEE,
    "300",
    "0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625",
    "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c",
    "9280",
    "500000",
  ];

  const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: 6,
  });
};
```

Here is my updating frontend code.

```js
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs");

const FRONT_END_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FILE =
  "../html-smartContract-fcc/constants/contractAddress.json";
const FRONT_END_ABI_FILE = "../html-smartContract-fcc/constants/abi.json";

module.exports = async function () {
  if (process.env.UPDATE_FRONT_END) {
    console.log("Updating the front end...");
    updateContractAddresses();
    updateABI();
  }
};

async function updateContractAddresses() {
  const raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle");
  const chainId = network.config.chainId.toString();
  const currentAddress = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(FRONT_END_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FILE, "utf-8")
  );
  if (chainId in currentAddress) {
    if (!currentAddress[chainId].includes(raffle.address))
      currentAddress[chainId].push(raffle.address);
  } else {
    currentAddress[chainId] = [raffle.address];
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    FRONT_END_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FILE,
    JSON.stringify(currentAddress)
  );
}

async function updateABI() {
  const raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle");
  fs.writeFileSync(
    FRONT_END_ABI_FILE,
    raffle.interface.format(ethers.FormatTypes.json)
  );
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "frontend"];
``
```

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your project folders architecture.